# Android BLE characteristic.getProperties returns an 'unknown' property'

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to work with Android BLE.  The Bluetooth thermometer I'm working work uses a Custom Characteristic to 'Notify' of temp measurements.

I am receiving the notifications via onCharacteristicChanged.  I can't, however, decifer what is coming through.

That's when I looked at the properties of the characteristic and it came back with '26'.  That doesn't appear to be a standard property.  Is there a way to figure out what this property is exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like poperty '26' is UTF-16 String. Found this from [this page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/format-types).